# How do I search between two times?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, time, rails-activerecord

How do I compare *only* time values using Rails and ActiveRecord? For instance, looking for all rows that were created after 3:00PM?

I tried using `Time.parse`, however they seem to be expecting a full DateTime value, not Time (11:00 PM etc).

I'm basically looking for all rows that exist between two dates, and then between two times. For example, all rows created between "21/01/2012" and "23/02/2012" that were created after "3:00PM". The date part seems to work fine, however I don't seem to be able to get the time part working without plain SQL.

Comment: Just to clarify what appears to be an assumption: `Time` contains both date and time components, just like the `DateTime` class. Learning the difference between the two is left as a research exercise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand you're applying a function to extract time from a datetime attribute in your SQL. Something like `select HOUR(created_at)`...

ActiveRecord can't do that, however the gem [squeel](https://github.com/ernie/squeel#functions) does it in Ruby.

```
Person.select{coalesce(name, '<no name given>')}
```

But there's nothing fundamentely different than doing it in plain SQL.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
User.where("created_at > ? and created_at < ?", Time.now - 3.days, Time.now)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, unfortunately that's not quite what I'm after. I need all records between two dates that start after a specified time. For example, all people who logged off after 5:00PM this financial year etc. Normally with straight SQL you'd just cast the datetime values, I'm curious as to whether there is a rails way of doing it? Thanks for the answer though, I appreciate the effort.

Comment: Do you mean something like this:  `User.all.select { |u| u.created_at.hour > 15 }` ?

Comment: Be careful with logic that looks like `created_at > ? and created_at < ?`. You have a condition that doesn't allow exact time matches. If it was 4:00 and `created_at` was 4:00, you'd never match it. Use `created_at >= ?` or `created_at <= ?`.